# Redis find keys where set includes element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis

I have a question regarding making Redis search for keys based on their attributes in a set. For example, I have an application that sends notifications and where, for a certain reason, I do not want to use a database to store the array of sent notifications, which I currently have to do. The application uses Ruby on Rails and ruby redis gem.
I have:

project.rb

```
def red
  red = Redis.new(:host => "localhost", :port => redis_port, :db => 3)
end 

# where I store the ids of notified users for the project
def notified_users
  red.smembers("projects:" + self.id.to_i.to_s + ":notifications")
end  

# method to add the user_id to notifications list, called from a background job that sends mails 
def notify!(user_id)
  red.sadd("projects:" + self.id.to_i.to_s + ":notifications", user_id.to_i)
end
```

The question is how do I find those project_ids, or at least the keys for all redis_objects, the set of which includes a certain user_id?
I am trying to write something like:

```
def self.notified_projects(user_id)
  # return all the keys from redis where user_id is inside a set
end
```

Maybe I missed something in the documentation, but I did not find any methods that do exactly that. 
I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redis is a key-value store, in key-value store mostly keys are searchable and part of queries(mostly). Instead of searching through the value set, I suggest you change your design somehow, so that you can represent the elements as keys instead of set values, which you can easily match with `wildcard`.

So, store your elements individually with their own key, and add that key identifier to your set.

```
'notification_set': ['project:343', 'project:3423']
'project:343': 'project 343 value'
'project:3423': 'project 3423 value'
```

There is `SSCAN` command to iterate over set values. Check it out:- [SSCAN](http://redis.io/commands/sscan)

Comment: I could design it the other way around, and store the notification keys for the user instead of the project, but the problem would be the other way around, getting the list of users for the given project that have been notified. I am looking for a system that would somehow work both ways.

Comment: How about storing reverse as well as combination of keys

Comment: I thought of that too, but that would mean I have to make all my methods do double work, and also make integrity test that make sure the synchronisation ran correctly... Because of that I am looking for something in redis that just does the same as postgresql `Project.where("ARRAY[?] && matched_users", self.id)` method of the users.rb, that does exactly what I need.

Comment: Not only that, in case the project status changes, for example, and I need to remove all prior notifications, currently I have to only delete the key, but if I store user set of notified projects, I would have to go through every user and get the project out of there as well. Given many thousand users per project that are notified, that is quite a problem in my case.

Comment: I'm not sure... how about using a combination of project id as well as user id in your key. that way you don't set either

Comment: I can imagine having something like having `email_notifications: [project_id1:user_id1, project_id2:user_id1]`. That would do what I need. I cannot find the method that gives me elements of the set matching a pattern though.

Answer (score -1):

I will mark the previous answer as the solution, but if someone is interested, here is the method I used that seems to work for me in production. Scan is a useful function capable of quickly filtering large amounts of set data based on pattern matching.

project.rb

```
def red
  red = Redis.new(:host => "localhost", :port => redis_port, :db => 3)
end 

def notify!(user_id)
  red.sadd("notifications", self.id.to_i.to_s + ":" + user_id.to_i.to_s)
  # to get a HUGE set of project_id:user_id
end 

def notified_users_raw
  red.sscan("notifications", 0, match: self.id.to_i.to_s + ":*", count: 1000*1000)[1]
end  

def notified_users 
  User.where(id: self.notified_users_raw.collect { |t| t.split(":")[1] })
end
```

same thing on user.rb

```
def notified_projects_raw
  red.sscan("notifications", 0, match: "*:" + self.id.to_i.to_s, count: 1000*1000)[1]
end  

def notified_projects 
  Project.where(id: self.notified_projects_raw.collect { |t| t.split(":")[1] })
end
```

The complexity is dependent on number of active projects times the number of active users, but the good thing about using Redis is that it can be deployed on a separate more powerful server, in case we face performance problems.